# Speeding up http web request in WCF invoked method

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, sms, httprequest

Hi I am writing a WCF service **not** hosted on IIS. It runs on my server as console application.
I have a static method that is invoked by the mentioned service.

In this method I have async web request that sends sms.

Sometimes it happens that sms is never recieved. After some debuging I found out that when I remove async call the web request sometimes throws an exception with message: 'The operation has timed out'. This happens when i try to send many smss in short period of time.

But when i type the address of the web request in browser everything works fine. (the times i press refresh, no matter how fast, that number of times i receive sms) how can this be achived with what i've got.

So far i have

```
    public static bool DoTheRequest(string number, string message)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format("http://SomeURL?With={0}&something={1}", number, message));
            myReq.BeginGetResponse(FinishWebRequest, myReq);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        return true;
    }

    static void FinishWebRequest(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        HttpWebResponse response = (result.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest).EndGetResponse(result) as HttpWebResponse;
    }
```

**EDIT:**

And the service definition:

```
    [OperationContract]
    void TestSms(string number);
```

and implementation:

```
    public void TestSms(string number)
    {
        Utilities.DoTheRequest(number, "THIS IS A TEST");
    }
```

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on *how many times* you are calling the send-sms function in a short period of time, I surmise that it's doing it a lot faster than you can refresh in your browser - and you're managing to flood whatever service it is you are using with your SMS calls.

In this scenario, I would suggest that your web-service method actually puts the SMS in to a queue, and some kind of a background worker thread that is designed not to throttle the API that actually sends the SMS, has the job of batching up these SMSs and sending them.

Better yet, to facilitate the issue that machines and software are not perfect, and lightning does indeed strike, I would suggest that you push SMSs in to some kind of back-end data store and leave it at that.  A background worker job/thread then has the job of finding all SMSs that are unsent and trying to send them (but sending no more than "x per minute"), each one being marked as "Sent" upon completion.

This has the added advantage that you can throw as many SMSs as you want at your backing data storage, if the machine dies it can pick up where it left off, and if you get some failures, they can be retried.

Comment: Tnx for the answer.
e.g. I send 1 sms and wait for it to be received then I send 2nd and wait for it to be received then i send 3rd and BOOM exception. In my browser i press refresh in a second (maybe less) and works great (no waiting for arrival). 
Thank you for the suggestion of using queue. But I was hopping for something I can do with what I have. Do you think that is possible? How does the browser do it? (chrome)

Comment: May I ask why you're waiting for it to be received?  SMSs are not delivered instantly and could take an inordinate amount of time to arrive.  Hence my suggestion of using a database where the state of transmission can be maintained in a request-agnostic manner.  My guess is that in your code, the thread pool is getting clogged up waiting for SMSs to be received, whilst in your browser-case, nobody is waiting on anyone else.  Just a guess, at this point.

Comment: You misunderstood me in my code i am not waiting for it. I am psychically waiting for it to be received. In example in above comment I send sms to my self and wait for the phone to ring.
My code is as in question so it's async call that I dont care what the response is.

Comment: Are you using a third-party SMS provider, and do they throttle your SMS sending?

Comment: This is the code i am sending with my application - BAD
And with my web browser - GOOD
It looks like http://SomeURL?With=Params&something=else